# Bootstrap dropdown not dropping down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out why this my drop down is not dropping down in bootstrap.  Could someone point me to the error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
   </head>
   <body>
  <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span12">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand" href="#">Prodata</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-target="#" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="manageLabel">Manage<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="manageLabel">
                            <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Surveys</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Job Numbers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" />
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was self closing the script tag.  It cannot be self closing.

Comment: Can you explain this further? What script tag is currently self closing in the code above? These? 

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"/>`    

`<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" />` ? What does it mean for it to not be "self-closing"?